# How to prevent changing specific module installed status during config syncs?

Tags: configuration

I know there are methods for preventing specific configurations from being exported but how do you prevent specific module's installed/un-installed status from being exported?

For example, I'd like dev,stage_file_proxy to be enabled on dev but not prod. And the reverse for mem_cache.

Also, is there a way to prevent the performance page settings (CSS, JS aggregation) from being exported?

Comment: Have you tried the [Config split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use`$settings['config_exclude_modules']` key in settings.php to exclude modules.

For example Refer [example.settings.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.4.x/sites/example.settings.local.php#L155)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can prevent the performance (aggregation) settings from exporting?

Comment: In a world where you sync a database from live to dev or local, this method is not really going to work very well. For example, it won't enable your dev modules or disable your live modules after syncing a database.

Comment: Yes, like this https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.4.x/sites/example.settings.local.php#L52

Comment: That doesn't prevent the settings from being exported - it only overrides the values on the environment with that settings.php file.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @sonfd.